# Why is timezone_menu returning a PHP formatted timezone instead CodeIgniter formatting (e.g. 'UP10') after upgrade to 2.6.1?

Tags: date, codeigniter, timezone

After upgrading ExpressionEngine from 2.5.2 to 2.6.1, the Member module now sets the member's localization to PHP format eg. 'Australia/Sydney' in the exp_members table.  So, when my site calls EEs Localize class it returns the PHP format instead of the CI format, that is it should return 'UP10' instead of 'Australia/Sydney', generating this error:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: Australia/Sydney
Filename: libraries/Localize.php
Line Number: 735
```

It may be that there is a bug in the javascript generated by the CI Date Helper function timezone_menu(), because the  tag should be generated with the latter time zone codes (i.e. Sydney).

The code for the localization_form view is generated on line 1563 of mod.member_settings.php:

```
'form:localization' =>  ee()->localize->timezone_menu(($query-  >row('timezone')  ==     '') 
? 'UTC' : $query->row('timezone'))
```

The javascript function that is generated is called 'ee_tz_change' (why the 'ee_' prefix in a CI generated function?).

The mod.member_settings module generates the localization form for the user using the Localize class in the edit_localization() function.

The Localize class uses the CI Date helper timezone_menu() function to generate a localization menu, but this provides the string 'Sydney/Australia' in the  tag, which means this is what is passed back to the update_localization() function in mod.member_settings.php.

See line 1593 in mod.member_settings.php:

```
$data['timezone'] = $_POST['server_timezone'];
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?  Where is this ee_tz_change js function coming from???

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting the same error, with EE 2.7.2. All I did was change my account timezone from "Belarus -> Minsk" (????) to my actual location. It triggered the exact same `Undefined index` error on the frontend. When I used Firebug to live-edit the My Account -> Localization Settings -> Select Time Zone form, changing `<option value="Asia/Jerusalem">` to `<option value="UP2">` and submitting it, the problem went away. Have you filed an official bug report I can join in on?

Comment: No Sandwhich, I wasn't certain whether it was actually a bug and I ran out of time so I couldn't pursue it any further.  Let me know if you discover anything.

Comment: Reported as a bug here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19909

Comment: Thanks for reporting this Sandwhich, I recall I did something similar to my form with the "UP2" thing.  Considering we have to pay for the Member module, I would think Ellislabs were more careful with changing this sort of code. Especially since they are so keen for us to upgrade our EE installations regularly.

Comment: If you look at the bug report, the Member module wasn't at fault in my situation - it was an old add-on that hadn't been updated for EE 2.6.x. In your case, the problem probably lies with your code. :-/